# What is the difference between Fuerte and ROS electric

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very confused  the difference between Fuerte and ROS electric.can you help me ?thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43613/what-is-the-difference-between-fuerte-and-ros-electric/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are different releases of ROS.

What is new/changed in fuerte is listed here:
http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-11**:
Yes. See also: http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration

**Comment by [agoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/3109/agoto/) on 2012-09-11**:
Also, Fuerte is the newest release (April 2012). It came up after Electric (August 2011).

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-09-11**:
reduced number of dependencies and faster than electric